# Maven is not using my classpath in my jar

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to setup a hello world example in Java using just Maven and the **command line** and everything worked nicely, except that the final .jar file looks like to be wrong.

My project has the following structure:

> ./pom.xml
>
> ./src/main/java/my/project/path/example/Example.class

And my pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.project.path</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jar</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>my.project.path.example.Example</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My final .jar file has a strucutre like this:

> ./Example.class
>
> ./META-INF/...

I'd expect it to be:

> ./my/project/path/example/Example.class
>
> ./META-INF/...

Java 7 and Apache Maven 3.0.4.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If you're having manifest issues (finding the main class), I personally use the maven compiler plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>br.usp.lta.Example</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also, make sure that your structure at the top matches:

```
<groupId>my.usp</groupId>
<artifactId>lta</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

And then your main class would be in `src/main/java/my/usp/lta/Example.class`. This compiled fine for me using your pom.

Comment: This is not what I want. I've updated my question to make it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual classpath, and the contents of your `src/main/java/` folder?

Comment: Oh wait, I see your issue, one moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dependencies, You can have `maven-dependency-plugin` to configure your main jar to refer in classpath. This is configured in Manifest file of main jar.
`maven-jar-plugin` helps in creating the executable jar

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.example.MyMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using a Java reserved word in your package name: 'class'. That won't compile.
In your pom file you need to add the maven jar plugin. Apart from the compiler plugin that is all you need. Example:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <configuration>
        <archive>
           <manifest>
              <mainClass>my.path.example.Example</mainClass>
           </manifest>
        </archive>
     </configuration>    
</plugin>
```

Comment: It's just an example: it's not the real one. I'll change it in the question.

Comment: It compiles, it just won't create the .jar file with the correct classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I was forgetting about the "package" declaration at the top of the file. According to the Java Language Specification:

> 7.4.2. Unnamed Packages
>
> A compilation unit that has no package declaration is part of an
>   unnamed package.
>
> Unnamed packages are provided by the Java SE platform principally for
>   convenience when developing small or temporary applications or when
>   just beginning development.
>
> An unnamed package cannot have subpackages, since the syntax of a
>   package declaration always includes a reference to a named top level
>   package.

So, adding the following line solved the issue:

```
package my.project.path.example;
```